# UITableViewCell holding UICollectionView and click collection cell segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I am using Swift3 and Xcode 8.3.3
I am working on UITableViewCell which hold UICollectionView.
Each CollectionView cell need to perform segue.
I mean, i need to call other ViewController with Navigation Controller. So user can back to Main UITableViewController.

```
import UIKit

class PastCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ptripDtls: UICollectionView!

    var logcount:Int = 0
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        ptripDtls.delegate = self
        ptripDtls.dataSource = self
        logcount = Transfer.tripObj[Transfer.cellpos]["logcount"]! as! Int

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let width = self.ptripDtls.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.width;
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width-17 , height: 50)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        ptripDtls!.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}

extension PastCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return logcount
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PastTripCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! PastTripCollectionCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Might be here segue function will call
    }

}
```

Comment: so you want to call another view controller when collection view cell is selected

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constant.vc.DestinationVC) as! DestinationVC
         self.show(vc, sender: self) 
write this two line of code in your didselect

Comment: @GoribDeveloper This is custom cell which is holding Collection. So i can't use your function.

Comment: @V_rohit yes using Navigation so i can get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually multiple choices here:

#### Closure

Pass a closure inside the `UITableViewCell` like `tapped: (Model) -> Void` when you're dequeuing a tableView cell, and specify inside that closure to perform a segue. (it works if all your collection cells will perform a same segue, you can use this mechanism to propagate your callback if different segue's should get called)

#### Delegate

Define a custom delegate, to inform your viewController about CollectoinView's DidSelectItem method, and then perform Segue accordingly.

#### Notification

Trigger a Notification throughout the system which only your ViewController listens to that notification, and perform your segue accordingly. (This isn't actually a good solution, just pointing out that it's possible)

Comment: I agree with your suggestions let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4 Use perform segue inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath if you are using segue

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
```

and use Push if you are using only navigation controller.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVCIdentifier") as! YourVC

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I already written i am working on swift3 also Table Custom Cell class holds the Collection and collection cell need to perform segue.